# Есть ли аналог директивы try_files в Nginx для работы с удаленными файлами?

Tags: nginx

Как я понимаю, try_files умеет работать только с локальными файлами. Мне нужно решить похожую задачу, но файлы в нашем случае лежат в S3 и мы обращаемся туда с помощью proxy_pass (все это в отдельном location). Очень надеялся, что NGINX каким-то хитрым образом примет этот самый location за файл и я все смогу сделать с помощью той же конструкции try_files. Но не тут то было.

Собственно вопрос - нет ли готового решения для данной задачи?

Спасибо!

Comment: google://mount+s3+bucket

Comment: И что мешает проверять ответ на предмет ошибки 404?

Comment: @AlexeyTen имеете ввиду использовать директиву error_page?

Comment: Да. И не забыть про `proxy_intercept_errors`

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, такой вариант вполне подойдет. Спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeyTen, оформите, пожалуйста, ваши комментарии в виде ответа.